# STARTTLS failure

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, tls

Estoy intentando configurar un sistema de notificaciones a través de correo electronico y no consigo hacerlo funcionar correctamente.

El Framework usado es **Efront Version 3.6**. Que tiene dos carpetas PEAR y ZEND pero no son estas para lo mismo? ¿frameworks para el envio de emails?

https://github.com/epignosis/efront_open_source

Poseo un servidor de correo electronico con certificado digital... pero para hacerlo mas facil deberia poder hacerlo con gmail como muestro abajo y tampoco es posible...

> SMTP SERVER - smtp.gmail.com
>
> SMTP USER - Mi correo de GMAIL.
>
> SMTP PASSWORD - Mi contraseña de GMAIL.
>
> SERVER SMTP PORT - 587(TLS) o 465(SSL).

Cuando pulso sobre Comprobar configuración obtengo...

Usando el puerto **587** un problema que ocurre bastante he encontrado similares en internet pero ninguna solución...

```
authentication failure [SMTP: STARTTLS failed (code: 220, response: 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS)]
```

Usando el puerto **465**, la pagina se queda cargando hasta que obtengo un `timeout` 300 segundos después.

El modulo **OpenSSL** esta activado en el servidor y el **certificado digital** es correcto y valido... Las lineas del **php.ini** que requieren la url del certificado también...

```
openssl.cafile="C:\direccion\certificado.crt"
```

La versión de PHP usada es la 5.6 y en previas versiones si funcionaba correctamente pero he encontrado que a partir de esta versión se modificó lo siguiente...

https://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

Es esto lo que me esta dando el problema creo... ¿Que se debe hacer entonces?

Estos errores citados son generados desde los archivos de PHP...

> localhost\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php -- Que lanza la frase STARTTLS failed

```
    if ($tls && version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.0', '>=') &&
        extension_loaded('openssl') && isset($this->_esmtp['STARTTLS']) &&
        strncasecmp($this->host, 'ssl://', 6) !== 0) {


        /* Start the TLS connection attempt. */
        if (PEAR::isError($result = $this->_put('STARTTLS'))) {
            return $result;
        }
        if (PEAR::isError($result = $this->_parseResponse(220))) {
            return $result;
        }
        if (PEAR::isError($result = $this->_socket->enableCrypto(true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT))) {
            return $result;
        } elseif ($result !== true) {
            print_r($result);

            //error_reporting(E_ALL);
            return PEAR::raiseError('STARTTLS failed');

        }

        /* Send EHLO again to recieve the AUTH string from the
         * SMTP server. */
        $this->_negotiate();
    }
```

> localhost\PEAR\Net\SMTP.php -- Que lanza la frase authentication
>   failure

```
    /* Attempt to authenticate if authentication has been enabled. */
    if ($this->auth) {
        $method = is_string($this->auth) ? $this->auth : '';

        if (PEAR::isError($res = $this->_smtp->auth($this->username,
                                                    $this->password,
                                                    $method))) {
            $error = $this->_error("$method authentication failure",
                                   $res);
            $this->_smtp->rset();
            return PEAR::raiseError($error, PEAR_MAIL_SMTP_ERROR_AUTH);
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE #1** Los datos necesarios se envia desde un formulario como este...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aun asi hay varios archivos en el codigo que contienen atributos vacios y no se si es necesario rellenarlos.

```
PEAR/Net/Socket.php

PEAR/Net/SMTP.php

PEAR/Mail/smtp.php
```

Todos estas clases tiene atributos como `host, port, user, password`...
Que logicamente se inicializan a '' entiendo porque se cogen del formulario...

Comment: En la pantalla *System Settings > Integrations > Mail* ¿tienes seleccionado **Auto TLS**?.

Comment: No me aparece esa pestaña... Desde System Settings puede acceder a General Settings, User Settings, Appearance, External Tool y Customization. En ninguno de sus campos me aparece la opción del Auto TLS.

Comment: No sé cómo se maneje en tu código o en las librerías de PEAR, pero aconsejo revisar que esté intentand STARTTLS sin SSL. Me pasó con una app que intentaba autenticarse y no funcionaba si uno habilitaba comunicación SSL al tiempo con STARTTLS

Comment: Si SSL esta activado y el modulo correspondiente se encuentra en el servidor. En el primer trozo de codigo de la pregunta puedes ver que entra dentro del primer if... luego extension_loaded('openssl') es true

Comment: Como sugerencia, indica la versión del framework. Eso también permite que quienes intenten responder descarten cosas. La pregunta que te hicieron coincide con la documentación actual; si no tienes esa opción, posiblemente uses una versión anterior y debas entenderte con el proveedor del software https://support.efrontlearning.com/hc/en-us/articles/114094215012-How-to-set-up-your-SMTP-server

Comment: No sé si pueda estar relacionado (PHP no es lo mio, pero conozco algo del protocolo SMTP por lo que puede ser relevante). Antes de intentar STARTTLS, el cliente debe enviar un comando EHLO al servido. No sé si tu biblioteca PHP lo hará por defecto, pero no creo, el saludo habitual suele ser HELO. Quizás hay un parámetro para que sea EHLO, o quizás tengas que enviarlo "a mano" con un `$this->put()`.

Comment: if (PEAR::isError($error = $this->_put('EHLO', $this->localhost))) {
            return $error;
        } // Este no lanza nigun error... Creo que esto se esta realizando correctamente

Comment: Efront Version 3.6

Comment: https://github.com/epignosis/efront_open_source // Este es el repositorio por si alguien lo quiere probar... sigue apareciendo el problema de StartTLS...

Comment: los comentarios que dicen parece que el error no es de programa sino de configuracion del servidor, probablemente tengas que hacer algo mas en el firewall de windows y si no es el de windows en la consola de Azure

Comment: POR FAVOR, no pongas ese update diciendo que funcionó. Pon como respuesta lo que hiciste para que funcionara y la aceptas si es la solución a tu problema

Answer (score -1):

Dice el OP:

> He conseguido hacerlo funcionar.
>
> SOLUCIÓN: Descargar las ultimas versiones de todos los Modulos PEAR.